# The chassan giving berachos on the day of his wedding

Tags: blessing, shidduchim-dating, chassan-groom

I heard from someone that the *chasan* - on the day of his *chuppah* - can give unmarried bochurim a berachah to find a shidduch.

Is there a source for this?

Comment: Anyone can give anyone a blessing for anything whenever.